# Model Selection in Physics

Tags: experimental-physics, soft-question, statistics, models

My understanding of the [scientific method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) is that it can be summarized in the following steps that don't need to be executed in any particular order:

> - Make conjectures & hypotheses (i.e. develop models and theories)
> - Make predictions from them
> - Carry out experiments and/or collect data
> - Test and possibly embrace the new theories / models **IF**:
>
>   - the data fit model predictions more **accurately** than alternative theories
>   - the new theory is not more **complex** than other plausible (fitting) alternatives

In  **statistics** and **computational learning** we often encounter a similar [tension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection) between [goodness of fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) and [model complexity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/measures-of-model-complexity) when comparing models that aim to explain the data. To do this, we rely on **formal [model selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection) methods** such as the [Bayes factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor) and its approximations (e.g. [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), [BIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion), [deviance information criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_information_criterion), etc.), and often use [measures of model complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_description_length) and [validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) to decide what particular model to embrace.

### My question:

Are there any **examples** of these or similar **frameworks** in Physics that are used to **compare theories**?  In other words, are there any **information theoretic** frameworks researched / used in Physics that study this particular **tradeoff** between model **accuracy** and **complexity** to specifically inform **theory selection**?

Comment: While an *important* question, I think this question is, as you yourself acknowledge, *too broad* - there are many subfields, and they have very different standards of what is considered "evidence" or a "statistically significant observation". As a rule of thumb, I'd say physics embraces the scientific method *as best as possible* among all the sciences, which is to say, imperfectly of course.

Comment: "In theory there is no difference between theory and practice; in practice there is." - which can be seen in the fact that even Wikipedia is confused about who might have said this first and that it doesn't matter, at all, for its utter profoundness.

Comment: That overly simplistic model of the scientific method brings to mind an insurance company commercial currently playing in the US: *That's not how it works. That's not how any of this works.* Theoretical physicists rarely (if ever) conduct experiments; experimentalists rarely (if ever) develop new theories. The first test of a theory in physics is experiments that have already been performed. For example, relativity theory necessarily had to be consistent with Newtonian mechanics in the regime where Newtonian mechanics agreed well with experimental results.

Comment: [this recent article on Nature](http://www.nature.com/news/scientific-method-defend-the-integrity-of-physics-1.16535) about the relationship of the more recent trends of theoretical physics and the scientific method may be of interest

Comment: @DavidHammen Note that I didn't number the bullets in the list to highlight that the scientific method does not impose an order on whether you start with observations or with a theory. Also, formally speaking, predictions (at least in statistical theory) are not understood to mean forecasts about future observations. Finally, note that I added the clause "feel free to correct". You and everyone are more than welcomed to do so.

Comment: The scientific method HINGES on observations. Theory is just a tool to make sense of them. It's not about where you start (usually it all starts with an observation, by the way, not with theory) but what guides research, and that is always nature. There are no exceptions to that rule.

Comment: `the data fit the [theory's] predictions more accurately than alternative theories` As David Hammen pointed out, Newtonian mechanics are suitable for most interactions. Only when you get into the realm of very small or very fast does the calculated result differ from the data. Your statement indicates that we should dispose of Newtonian mechanics since it doesn't fit the data well and another theory does a better task. Sorry, I'm going to continue to use Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: In the spirit of LDC3s response it's important to mention that theory is inclusive. It allows for multiple explanations of the same observation to live side by side. We frequently trade simplicity of an explanation for precision or even ontological completeness. One can, in principle, calculate the motion of the planets with QED/QCD, but nobody in their right mind will do it. The great success of Newtonian mechanics is its simplicity and coverage of common phenomena. It will live on, long after the TOE has been discovered.

Comment: @LDC When you said: `Your statement indicates that we should dispose of Newtonian mechanics since it doesn't fit the data well and another theory does a better task.` That is **not** correct. The OP does not suggest that. Also, a bias for Newtonian mechanics can be justified from the angle that it is a  **simpler** theory (easier to apply and communicate) than other theories for some problems. This is the tension that the OP refers to: model complexity is an equally important aspect of **model/theory selection** in inference theory and of the **scientific method**.

Comment: @user815423426 - Re *Also, formally speaking, predictions (at least in statistical theory) are not understood to mean forecasts about future observations.*  Predictions are (almost) an absolute necessity in physics. There's little value in a new model/theory that doesn't predict some outcome that is at odds with the outcome predicted by existing models/theories. If no new prediction results, the new model/theory is at best a refinement to how one expresses the existing model/theory, but it's not new. New theories have to break new ground.

Comment: Science doesn't seek the rational pursuit of truth. Science simply seeks the most simple and best fitting explanations for natural observations. I would suggest that you separate romantic notions from your ideas about science and you stick to the fundamental definitions.

Answer (score 3):

I will comment and reorder your list, as a retired experimental particle physicist.

> ```
>    Make conjectures & hypotheses (theory)
> ```

Preexisting successful theories  with their postulates and strict mathematical models .  After all physics started before Newton.

> ```
>    Make predictions from this theory
> ```

Use the theory to predict behaviors in experiments carried out currently, to confirm/validate preexisting theories.

> ```
>    Carry out experiments and observations
> ```

Surprise , surprise experiment does not fit preexisting theory. Head scratching of experimentalists, fever by theoreticians.

Example: radioactivity needed special relativity and quantum mechanics to be modeled theoretically, and the observations existed long before the theories,  experimental data forced the need for new theories.

New theories appear:

> ```
>    Test and embrace the new theory if
>         the data fit the predictions more accurately than alternative theories
>         the new theory is not more complex than other plausible alternatives
> ```

No. Test and embrace the new theories for the new region of validity and make sure that the old theories can mathematically be shown to emerge from the new. For example: statistical mechanics the new theory, was shown to have as emergent theory Thermodynamics, an elegant mathematical model working well in its region of validity long before statistical mechanics was formulated.

Then design experiments that may show diversions from the current model leading to a deeper theoretical understanding, as now with the LHC the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) is being tested/validated and everybody is holding their breath that a discrepancy will be found leading to the need of hypothesized higher theories.

Physics does not progress by having a theorist propose a brand new  model to be checked. This has lead to a lot of crackpot proposals, with people not understanding why they are not treated as the new Einstein.

Einstein built upon the previous theories, certainly thinking outside the box, but his theories were based on the previous ones extending them for new regions of validity, and the join between the older theories and General relativity and special relativity is smooth and computable.  No  general  "out with the old in with the new" works for the scientific method in physics.

And to answer about statistical methods, all statistical methods are used in evaluating the goodness of fit of data to theories. Example the recent Higgs search and discovery at the LHC.

Also to keep in mind that in particle physics now, the specialty of theorist and experimentalist is necessary as the amount of knowledge and expertise needed in each branch is enormous. One symptom is the 3000 physicists signing the experimental papers of the LHC.

Comment: When experiments and theory don't agree, that's when scientists break out the champagne. It's the only way to make significant discoveries.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Or as Isaac Asimov wrote, "*The most exciting phrase to hear in science, the one that heralds new discoveries, is not 'Eureka!' but 'That's funny...'*"

Comment: @DavidHammen: I still wish I could have had more of those in my life. Sadly, most of the time what we got was what we were expecting to get. I am still looking forward to the next LHC run and my heart hopes for all the scientists there that they get a change to utter that phrase. So far I have seen a lot of disappointed faces, especially among the young folks who are analyzing the data. "The Higgs and not much else" would be an utterly devastating result for the largest experimental effort we have ever put up. There is still hope...

Comment: `"No. Test and embrace the new theories for the new region of validity and make sure that the old theories can mathematically be shown to emerge from the new."` Sorry, but this doesn't make sense. A single theory (i.e. simpler) that predicts **well** a wide set of phenomena is better than a collection of theories for each particular case. Full stop. This is the tension of **simplicity** and **accuracy** in the OP. Also, there were surely old mathematical models of the world around us that were incorrect. One does not have to "make sure" that such old incorrect models emerge from new theories.

Comment: @Josh  I am stating what I have observed in the progress of physics. In physics an established theory is a mathematical model on data.  I am not talking of incorrect models, I am talking of models which are correct in their region of validity, as Newtonian physics with respect to General Relativity. The word "model" means that a lot of data have been encapsulated in it. Making sure of consistency old with new is important in understanding both old and new, and validating the new.For example any new "standard model" of particle physics must necessarily embed/include/approximate the current one.

Comment: continued , in the region of validity of the old. The old is wrong in the region of validity of the new, that is why the new is necessary. simplicity is aesthetically satisfying but not necessary. accuracy of course is necessary in any experimental discipline.